# RestSharp POST request for a cURL request

Tags: .net, restsharp

I am using Restsharp in .net as a web api client.I have tried multiple permutations and still its not working. It is giving the following error:

*Connection To Failed
The system returned:
(13)Permission denied.*

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -X POST -d "{\"name\":\"ask question from mediator1\",\"title\":\"ask question from mediator\",\"abstractText\":\"ask question from mediator\",\"editorialService\":\"CHINA\",\"plcRef\":\"a-000-2000\"}"  http://mynetworkserver:8081/ask/asset
```

The code that I am using:

```
   RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = "http://mynetworkserver:8081/ask/asset"; // **Is this url correct?**
       RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
 var fQuestion = new FQuestion
            {
                name = "ask question from mediator 1",
                title = "ask question from mediator",
                abstractText = "ask question from mediator",
                editorialService = "CHINA",
                ref = "A-000-0023"
            };      
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.Resource = "asset"; **// What is this?**
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddBody(fQuestion);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```